# Connecting to SQL Server using Perl using DBI?

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, dbi

I am trying to connect to SQL server using Perl DBI module, I have tried all the connection string format still Perl is throwing invalid connection string error.

I have already tried code snippet available on perl monk website.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI;

# Set up variables for the connection
my $server_name = '00.120.124.1;3181';

my $database_name = 'abcd';
my $database_user = 'kkkk';
my $database_pass = 'password';

my $DSN = 'driver={SQL Server};server=$server_name;da
+tabase=$database_name;uid=$database_user;pwd=$database_pass;'; 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$DSN") || die "Couldn't open database
+: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Expected result is to connect to Database.

failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000) [state was 01000 now 01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (SQL-01S00) at perl.pl line 16. Couldn't open database +: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000] Invalid connection string attribute (SQL-01S00)

Comment: Still getting, invalid string attribute.

Comment: Do you have a literal newline and + in the DSN string your real code or is that just some strange copy & paste error?

Comment: And what is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000) [state was 01000 now 01S00]
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (SQL-01S00) at perl.pl line 16.
Couldn't open database
+: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
Invalid connection string attribute (SQL-01S00)

Comment: That should go in your post, not a comment, so it has a chance of being readable. You should also include the value of the DSN string as it's being passed to `DBI->connect()`.

Comment: `00.120.124.1` is not a valid IP address, and hence, likely isn't a valid hostname either.

Comment: Ooo. If arguments are separated by semicolons, that port number might be being treated as one, and without a name causing an error?

Answer (score 2):

The lines of your post that begin with `+`

```
+tabase=$database_name;uid=$database_user;pwd=$database_pass;'; 

+: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

were incorrectly copied and pasted from perlmonks.org. The leading `+` sign is a convention that indicates a long line was split. You should delete the `+` and join the line to the previous line, so that your code will read

```
my $DSN = 'driver={SQL Server};server=$server_name;database=$database_name;uid=$database_user;pwd=$database_pass;'; 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$DSN") || die "Couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message contains the following:

> SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Your set-up code contains the following:

> ```
> my $server_name = '00.120.124.1;3181';
> ```

'00.120.124.1;3181' is not a valid server name or IP address. You should correct the IP address section (it can't start with '00') and remove the port into a separate parameter.

You also have the username and password as part of your DSN. I don't know if DBD::ODBC supports that usage (it's not mentioned in [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC)) but it's more traditional to have those as separate parameters to the `connect()` call.

All in all, I think you want something more like this:

```
my $server_name = '00.120.124.1'; # But this needs to be corrected
my $server_port = 3181;

my $database_name = 'abcd';
my $database_user = 'kkkk';
my $database_pass = 'password';

my $DSN = "driver={SQL Server};server=$server_name;port=$server_port;database=$database_name"; 

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$DSN", $database_user, $database_pass)
  || die "Couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Also note that I've changed the quote characters used to create your `$DSN` variable from single quotes to double quotes. Variables are not expanded in signel quotes, so you weren't getting the values of `$server_name`, etc. in your DSN.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to connect is with the DBD::Sybase module.  The name wouldn't suggest it but SQL Server takes its lineage from Sybase.  That way you can avoid ODBC. http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Sybase#Using-DBD::Sybase-with-MS-SQL